# primitive root mod25

Tags: modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

3. Verify that 2 is a primitive root mod 25.

I just want to make sure my understanding of what a primitive root is is clear. So to show my work I calculated 2^1mod25 up to 2^24mod25, and showed that all values 1-24 that are relatively prime with 25, (so excluding 5,10,15 and 20) are represented. Is this the correct way of thinking?

Comment: @lhf oh! I figured there must be a faster way. would you mind explaining the logic behind why that proves it though?

Comment: The order of any element that is relatively prime to 25 must divide $\phi(25)=20$, which is the total order, since there are $\phi(25)$ elements that are relatively prime to 25.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct, though there are faster ways to prove that.

$2$ is a primitive root $\bmod 25$ iff $20$ is the smaller positive exponent $n$ such that $2^n \equiv 1 \bmod 25$.

Since $a^{20} \equiv 1 \bmod 25$ for all $a$ coprime with $25$, you only need to prove that $2^{10} \equiv -1 \bmod 25$, which is immediate, since $2^{10}=1024$.

Comment: It is a priori not sufficient that $2^{10}\equiv-1\pmod{25}$ for $2$ to be a primitive root. For example, $7^{10}\equiv-1\pmod{25}$, but $7$ has order $4$.